# How to rename multiple directories?

Tags: bash, directory, rename

Here are my directories:

```
P [001]
P [002]
P [003]
```

I want to rename to:

```
P001
P002
P003
```

I used the code:

```
for P in *\ *; do mv '$P' '${P// /_}'; done
```

but I am missing something.

Comment: Error: No $P in directory

Comment: I tried revome spaces first from filename.

Comment: Single quotes inhibit evaluation of any variables inside them: `'$P'` is literally `$P`, hence your message. Double quotes allow such evaluation to proceed, so `"$P"` works (for some definition of "works").

Comment: You could try something like the following `for dir in *\ *; do d="${dir// \[/}"; echo mv -- "$dir" "-->" "${d/\]/}"; done`. When satisfied, you can remove `echo` from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with below to remove spaces (actually you are replacing with underscore), but you needed to use double quotes instead of single quotes which it will prevent variable expansion.

In addition, you should also know that since you are not validating the `P` variable if it's a directory or a file, might you will have a rename of files.

```
for P in *\ *;
do
    [ -d "$P" ] && mv "$P" "${P// /_}" || echo 'skipping, the'"$P"' is not a directory'
done
```

You can also do as following to remove all space/brackets:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'P*' -exec bash -c 'echo ${1} ${1//[][ ]}' bash {} \;
./P [001] ./P001
./P [002] ./P002
./P [003] ./P003
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `prename`

```
$ ls
P [001]  P [002]  P [003]
$ prename 's/[ \[\]]//g' P\ *
$ ls
P001  P002  P003
$
```

Alternatively, sticking with your original scripted approach (with a minor tweak of `'` to `"` and a slight change to the regexp)

```
$ ls
P [001]  P [002]  P [003]
$ for P in *\ *; do mv "$P" "${P//[\[\] ]/}" ; done
$ ls
P001  P002  P003
$
```

Comment: be aware you don't rename the file as you are not validating!

Comment: thx, now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Beware if the directories are inside each other, in other words, if you are doing it recursively, non of the answers above works (perhaps `prename` works , I am not sure). e.g.:

```
P [1]
   |___P [10]
   |___P [11]
         |___P [112]
         |___other
               |___P [113]
P [21]
P [132]
```

you can use this without installing any packages:

```
find . -type d -name 'P [*' -printf "echo mv \'%h/%f\' \'%h/\$(echo %f | sed \"s/[][ ]//g\")\'\n" | sort -r | sh
```

for testing and to do actual work :

```
find . -type d -name 'P [*' -printf "mv \'%h/%f\' \'%h/\$(echo %f | sed "s/[][ ]//g\")\'" | sort -r | sh
```

Explanation:
Look in current folder (`find .`) and find all directories (`-type d`) which names match (`- name 'P [*'`) and print a command which will be passed to `sh` for execution. `printf` replaces %h and %f with path-to and name of found files. The part `$(echo %f | sed 's/[][ ]//g')` asks the `sed` command to replace (`s/`) brackets and spaces( [`][` ] ) to nothing (`//`)in all of the filename (`g`). The important par is to reverse sort (`| sort -r`) these commands before running them (`| sh`) otherwise you may have renamed a parent folder before renaming it's child and the command fails.

Hope it is useful.

Edit: fixed problem with white space in name thanks to @AdminBee

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should use double quotes around `$P`

the following should do the job, even if it's not a single command :

```
for P in *\ *; do rename "s/ //g" * && rename "s/[][]//g" *; done
```

the first rename remove the whitespace, the second remove the square brackets

Comment: be aware you don't rename the file as you are not validating!